# GUI extension DLL in its own folder (not bin)

Tags: web8, gui-extensions

I've developed a GUI extension (I'm using Tridion Web 8). Now, I'd like to isolate the DLLs as much as possible to avoid loose anything in a future upgrade.

Is there anyway to put all the DLLs and files related to my GUI extension in a folder and reference them instead of putting them all in the Drive: `[Tridion Folder]\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin` folder?

I already tried to create a virtual folder in IIS, put everything in there and in the configuration use:

```
<vdir>MyExtension</vdir>
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself, but I suppose that `including the dll in the GAC` would be enough for the extension to work.

Looking for information about loading dll's out of the bin folder, it must work the following solution:
Create an `App.config` file for the extension (inside the Configuration folder) and include a reference to the dll with the following element:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly2"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="307041694a995978"/>
            <codeBase version="1.0.1524.23149" href="FILE://C:/Myassemblies/MyAssembly2.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Changing the values of **name**, **publicKeyToken**, **version** and **href** with your own values.

Comment: Hi Raul, sorry in the delay to answer...I'll try it tomorrow...and if it works I'll mark you reply as the correct answer. Thx!

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try to build Alchemy plugin, I have build couple of plugins and everything is managed by alchemy app